# Timing belt illustration meaning?

Tags: timing-belt

[image: Photo of Gates timing belt box]

As you may see at the example photo,there is an illustrations how the timing belt should be installed and there is a small arrow with the letter T that heading towards the middle point of the timing belt between the camshaft and the water pump(red arrow 1).
I have noticed that this letter is shown also at other models.
Does this T letter mean Tension?(so the tension should be checked at this point?)
or it means something else?

Comment: I believe your thought is correct, all the examples I have seen match where I would check the tension.  I have used the 'Contact Us' page on the Gates website to ask them the question.  If they answer, I will put their answer on here.